# Opinions on how to sum values based on multiple criterias

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, pivot-table, criteria

I am looking for opinions on how to best resolve the below. I regularly receive a list of raw data in table 1 which has a list of values per projects and codes. I then need to sum up the values from table 1 into table 2 based on the codes mentioned in the user reference and project column (starting with A2 for project 1 & A4 for project 2). The same codes can be used for both projects simultaneously.

so far, I use a pivot table and sumif function but it is not clean and efficient enough.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion if the steps involved are taking long time every time you are creating the report it is better to make a small macro to do these steps, you will have to run the macro one time and the report will be created itself

You have to make the macro dynamic in such a way that it can understand and perform accordingly to the changes in data

The changes that might occur can be:

- The list of User References can grow
- The input data in table 1 which you re receiving from external source can change with time, like column headers and number of columns (which results in broken formulas and pivot tables)
- Project and project codes can increase

So first create a structure manually that can cater for all these future changes and finalize your report

then make a macro to replicate all the above steps using macros.

At the end you will just have to run that once.

As a note:

If you are using macro to automate the report, it is better to use Pivot table as it is usually faster than sumifs formulas.

If you want to do it manually it is better to use only formulas, because for pivots you will have to refresh it on every data change, while formulas will automatically be updated